# What's a word for the shape of the space among the trees in a forest?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, science, compound-adjectives

I'm writing a proposal that contrasts systems with two different geometries. I'm looking for a word or short phrase (preferably non-technical), that would describe one of the geometries, which is space analogous to the space under a forest canopy and among the trees plus the gaps in the canopy and clearings, i.e. all the air space in the forest.

For comparison, the other system I'm describing is the vertebrate circulatory system, which can be described as a tree of vessels.

Some words I've considered are *anastomosing* and *reticulum*/*reticulated* but both words miss some aspects of the system I'm trying to describe (the clearings/gaps in the canopy) and also describe some parts of the system I'm contrasting it with (the vascular system).

Comment: There's *glade/gladed*, but I'm not sure it works for you.  There's also *arbor*, the same.

Comment: Anecdotally there is a german childrens song going like this: _What trees must they be,
Where the big elephants go for a walk,
Without bumping against them?
Right are the trees, left are the trees,
And in between are the spaces in between,
Where the big elephants go for a walk
Without bumping against them!_

Comment: Can we get an example sentence for this word?  I'm curious if you're looking for something more clinical or more poetic.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you're curious.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_shyness

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on a *forestry* or *biology* site?

Comment: If you want to get very simple, "forest" standing alone pretty much captures the entire system.

Comment: I like the children's song. The sentence I want is something like "in vertebrates, blood flows through a hierarchically branching system of vessels, but in these organisms fluid flows through a [word/phrase that describes the shape of the space]." Perhaps ohwilleke is right that saying 'forest-like space' would be okay.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The word "interstice" comes to mind. I'm a biology graduate and we referred to the space between the body's tissues as the interstitial space.

***Interstice*** — [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interstice)

> (noun) usually interstices ; An intervening space, especially a very small one
>
> *"sunshine filtered through the interstices of the arching trees"*

Comment: This is close. It suggests one important features of the geometry – interconnected voids, as among sand grains – but not the structure of those voids and their connections. Might be the best I can do though.

Comment: Oh, yeah - there is also it's adverb: "Interstitial" - as in "interstitial fluid", or "interstitial space" (albeit a little redundant). .

Answer (score 10):

There is a concept in graphic design known as ***negative space*** which I think covers your intended meaning perfectly - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space) has a decent article on it.

Comment: This is too generic on its own, but maybe as a phrase "a space like the negative space of a forest" would work.

Answer (score 8):

How about "interspace"?

```
noun
 ˈɪntəspeɪs/
1.
a space between things.
"the narrow interspaces between cells"
```

I think in all its simplicity "void" would also work well for your purpose.

Comment: This seems to be the generic word for space between things. Probably works well with everything.

Comment: This is too generic: could describe any geometry.

Comment: While I agree with your accepted answer, I don't actually think the definition of interstice, describes geometry any clearer than interspace.

Answer (score 3):

The space between the trees is most commonly known as the [**forest floor**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Forest_floor), then above that is the **[understorey layer](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Understory)** & above that the **[canopy layer](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Canopy_(biology))**.

Reference: Wikipedia

Comment: That typically describes the plants, etc. in that space, not the space itself; or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

How about **interarboreal space**?

OD:

> [arboreal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/arboreal):
>   Relating to trees.